# can push to heroku but get permission denied when pushing to git

Tags: git, heroku

I have a git repo hosted at Github to which I have pushed numerous commits. However, today when attempting to do a `git push` I got this error:

```
$ git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Now, before telling me this is a dupe of the many other "git push permission denied" issues, please note that I am able to successfully deploy to Heroku:

```
$ git push heroku

......

-----> Launching... done, v19
   http://hidden-inlet-6102.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.suggestion-box-app:hidden-inlet-6102.git
6e69075..243b0c8  master -> master
```

How can it be that I am able to push to Heroku but not to Github? I don't think I have made any changes to the repo since the last time I was able to successfully push a commit.

I tried (re?)-adding the SSH-key, but still get the same error when trying to push:

```
$ ssh-add
Identity added: /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa)
$ git push
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Any suggestions as to how I can address this issue would be appreciated.

Below is some additional reference info that might help solve this issue. Thanks in advance for any help!

```
    $ ssh -vT git@github.com
    OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011
    debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/Anders/.ssh/config
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
    debug1: Applying options for *
    debug1: Connecting to github.com [207.97.227.239] port 22.
    debug1: Connection established.
    debug1: identity file /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
    debug1: identity file /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
    debug1: identity file /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
    debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github9
    debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze1+github9 pat OpenSSH*
    debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
    debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.6
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
    debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
    debug1: Host 'github.com' is known and matches the RSA host key.
    debug1: Found key in /Users/Anders/.ssh/known_hosts:1
    debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: /Users/Anders/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    Permission denied (publickey).
```

And the repositories I am tracking:

```
$ git remote -v
heroku  git@heroku.suggestion-box-app:hidden-inlet-6102.git (fetch)
heroku  git@heroku.suggestion-box-app:hidden-inlet-6102.git (push)
origin  git@github.com:andersr/suggestion-box-app.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:andersr/suggestion-box-app.git (push)
```

Comment: try running `ssh-add -l` as per [THIS POST](https://help.github.com/articles/error-permission-denied-publickey)

Comment: You should try re-adding your public key, `id_rsa.pub`, to your Github account through github.com.

Comment: Re-added my keys following [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) - that fixed it.  Thanks!!!

Comment: Great!  Please enter that link as an answer and mark the question as answered.  It's okay to answer your own questions: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @patrickmdnet didn't realize I could answer my own question. Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

Followed the advice from [@Ric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2089625/ric) and re-added my public key, using [these instructions](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys), which solved the issue. Thanks everyone for your help!